# Cocoa bindings issue with three tableviews

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

im a osx-dev noob that is trying to build an application with three table views that will show the content of a core data store entity. But each table view is filtered on the attribute "status" of the entity.

the problem occurs when i also want to show the selected entity in textfields. I'm using three different array controllers with different fetch predicates. But in a textfield i can only bind the value to one array controller.

should i ditch the bindings and do it all programaticly or is there a simple solution to this? :)

here is an screenshot so you can grasp my app description.
[image]

Comment: You want the text fields below to show the most recent selection from the three tables above?  The three tables' selections aren't in sync?  There can be a different entity selected in each one?

Answer (score 0):

Keep bindings to populate the text fields if it satisfies what you want to do with this GUI.  I'd add an `NSObjectController` to control the one entity those fields represent.  If you want the user's changes to those fields persisted, bindings are still awesome.

But I think with three tables that might control what's displayed in the text fields, you're going to need to have some sort of non-binding glue code that determines which of the tables wins.  You can probably do everything you want by implementing some of the `NSTableViewDelegate` protocol.

If the text fields should display the last entity that the user clicked in any of the tables, simply have each table call the same `tableViewSelectionDidChange` delegate function.   All three tables could have the same delegate.  You can then call `setContent` on the `NSObjectController` from that function.

You could also use similar glue code to prevent more than one selection in any of the three tables, by having the same delegate function deselect everything in the other tables either through the view or the controller.  But that's up to you and needs consideration of whether you want multiple selection, etc.